# Write to child process on standard input, then exit parent process while child process is still running

Tags: c#, asynchronous, process, ipc

I'm writing a C# console application, where I have a process that spawns a child process and passes it a large string on the child process's standard input using `Process.StandardInput.WriteLine(mes)`.  The problem I'm having is that it seems that the `Process.StandardInput.WriteLine(mes)` on the parent process doesn't return until the child process terminates, at which point the parent process continues and completes.

I need a way to send the message to the child process in standard input and then terminate the parent process and let the child process continue running.

I think the program is easy to follow.  The parent process calls `SendOutput()` which calls the `Process.StandardInput.Writeline(mes)`.  After which I would hope it would continue on to the `Exit()` call.  The child process just reads the string in with `Console.ReadLine()`.

***Parent Process Code***

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\jobprinty\jobprintyDlite2020.exe";

    Process process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
    process.Start();

    string message = GetConsoleInput();

    sendOutput(process, message);

    System.Environment.Exit(0);

}

public static void sendOutput(Process p ,string mes)
{
    p.StandardInput.WriteLine(mes);
}
```

***Child Process Code***

```cs
public static String GetConsoleInput()
{
    String line = null;
    String completeline = null;

    //reads from standard input into string, "complete line"
    do
    {
        line = Console.ReadLine();
        if (line != null) Console.WriteLine("--" + line);

        //line = line + Environment.NewLine;
        if (line != null) line = line.Trim();

        completeline = completeline + line + Environment.NewLine;

    } while (line != null);

    //delete extra white space from input, complete line
    completeline = completeline.Trim();
    return completeline;

}
public static void Main(string[] args)
{

    //------recieve args from console
     completeline = GetConsoleInput();
```

Comment: If you were writing this in C against the win32 api, you could create a pipe with a larger buffer. Looks like dotnet (core) uses the default OS pipe size (https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Diagnostics.Process/src/System/Diagnostics/Process.Windows.cs#L831)

Comment: Perhaps you could create a larger pipe, replace the standard in handle of the *parent* process, then create the child without redirecting stdin, then the child should inherit the handle?